# Is there a way to have a self-sizing collection view within a self-sizing collection view cell using compositional layout?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I want to use compositional layout to create a simple list collection view -- cells are 100% width, and their height is dynamic based on their content. The content of each cell will be a collection view that will occupy the full width of its parent cell and its height should be dynamic based on its content, and the resulting height of it should determine the height of the parent cell that contains it.

I'm currently using this layout for the list view:

```
static func autoListLayout(rowHeight: CGFloat, padding: CGFloat) -> UICollectionViewLayout {
    let itemSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1), heightDimension: .estimated(rowHeight))
    let item = NSCollectionLayoutItem(layoutSize: itemSize)
    item.contentInsets = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets.zero
    let groupSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1), heightDimension: .fractionalHeight(1))
    let group = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.vertical(layoutSize: groupSize, subitems: [item])
    group.interItemSpacing = .fixed(padding)
    let section = NSCollectionLayoutSection(group: group)
    section.orthogonalScrollingBehavior = .none
    section.contentInsets = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(top: padding, leading: 0, bottom: padding, trailing: 0)
    section.interGroupSpacing = padding
    let layout = UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout(section: section)
    return layout
}
```

And the collection view being added into the cells of this list looks like this:

```
addSubview(subCollectionView)
subCollectionView.isScrollEnabled = false
subCollectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
subCollectionView.setContentHuggingPriority(.required, for: .vertical)
subCollectionView.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.required, for: .vertical)
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    subCollectionView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leftAnchor),
    subCollectionView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rightAnchor),
    subCollectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor),
    subCollectionView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor),
])
```

And the layout for that collection view as constructed as follows:

```
static func subLayout(rowHeight: CGFloat, padding: CGFloat) -> UICollectionViewLayout {
    let itemSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .estimated(30), heightDimension: .estimated(rowHeight))
    let item = NSCollectionLayoutItem(layoutSize: itemSize)
    item.contentInsets = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets.zero
    let groupSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1), heightDimension: .fractionalHeight(1))
    let group = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.horizontal(layoutSize: groupSize, subitems: [item])
    group.interItemSpacing = .fixed(padding)
    let section = NSCollectionLayoutSection(group: group)
    section.orthogonalScrollingBehavior = .none
    let layout = UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout(section: section)
    return layout
}
```

This is not resulting in the correct sizing though. The collection view within the cells is not sizing to fit its content and the cell that contains it is thus not being sized to fit the collection view inside (because the internal collection view has a resulting height of 0)

I realize that compositional layout is supposed to eliminate the need for nesting collection views in this manner but I have a use case where it would be helpful if I could do it this way.

Any ideas?